# number_in_month exercise (Don't understand why I'm getting "Syntax Error at EOF" in SML)

Tags: smlnj

I'm supposed to write a program that takes a list of dates and then a month and returns the number of dates that include the month.  I keep getting a syntax error and I don't understand why.

```
fun number_in_month (dates : int list, month : int) =   
    let val tally = 0
    in
        let fun tally_counter(tally_dates : int list)=      
                if (tally_dates[1]) = month 
                then (
                     tally = tally + 1
                     tally_counter(tl tally_dates)
                     )
                else if null (hd tally_dates)
                     then tally
        in 
            tally_counter(dates)
        end
```

Comment: Note that `tally = tally + 1` isn't an assignment, it's a comparison (which is false).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the `end` statement for your outermost `let`, as well as an `else` clause to your second `if` statement.

Certainly, the first of these will cause a syntax error at EOF. I'm not sure about the second one, but I believe that it will as well.